# error 500 when codeigniter is on live server, OK when local

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using codeignitor based product with below mentioned htaccess file. it works fine in local but when I upload it on my hosting server it gives 500 error. When I remove the .htaccess file it works fine but htaccess file is necessary, without it inner classes gave 404 error.

```
#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
Options All -Indexes

php_value post_max_size 10000M

php_value upload_max_filesize 10000M
```

Thanks

Comment: Your server may not allow you to set php.ini values in your htaccess file

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite activated on your server?

Comment: I am using godaddy shared hosting, let me check the mod_rewrite

Comment: verify with your hosting company

Comment: Just check your error logs. No need to guess anything, it's all in there. See either apache2 errors or php errors. Both should be somewhere in /var/logs/apache, depending on your distribution.